# Sum the value in one column based on the value in another column - excel 2013

Tags: excel, excel-2013

I have 3 Columns, B,C and D.

Columns B,C,D will be updated periodically and the number of rows will be increased day by day.

Columns B contains NAME, C contains Quantity and D has Date value.

```
Name Qt Date
SSS 20  
SSS 30  
NNN 50  
PPP 40  13-Jul-15
PPP 20  13-Jul-15
AAA 20  
CCC 100 
GGG 300 
FFF 200 
BBB 50  28-Aug-15
AAA 20  
GGG 100 
BBB 30  
JJJ 50  
BBB 30  
FFF 50  
FFF 25  24-Aug-15
CCC 75  
JJJ 30  
FFF 50  
JJJ 36  24-Aug-15
FFF 50  24-Aug-15
```

I need the result as below.

```
Name Qt
AAA 40
BBB 30
CCC 175
FFF 300
GGG 400
JJJ 80
NNN 50
SSS 50
```

Rows with date field(column D) having a value should be omitted from adding.

Name field can contain any name and future names can vary from current names.

The Result can be in the same sheet or in the different sheet.

Comment: Have you used Pivot Tables before? They might be ideal for this scenario.

Comment: I believe, if I use pivot tables, restriction cant be applied. As I need to add the Qt. only for the rows whose date field is empty.

Comment: You can filter them out, but you would have to select blank in the filter manually after creating the table.

Answer (score 0):

This may not meet your exact needs but it should get you the data you want in the first instance.

1. In Excel select the **Insert** tab and select **Pivot Table**.
2. Set the table range to be A1 to C60000 (or whatever the max number of rows is)
3. Select **New Worksheet** and click **OK**.
4. Add the **Name** and **Qt** fields to the report. It should automatically sum Qt.
5. Add **Date** to the **Filters**. This should add a bar above the pivot table that says something like:
   `Date    (All)`
6. Click on **(All)** and select **(blank)**, and that should exclude the rows with dates specified.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion :) I tried but I have to keep on refreshing it, as everyday the data rows increases.

Comment: You can [set the workbook to automatically refresh the pivot table when you open the Excel file](https://support.office.com/en-us/Article/Update-refresh-data-in-a-PivotTable-d3f74ee2-0da7-4aef-8b2f-481bb2f18218) if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

use helper cells next to the date range =isblank(d2) this will return TRUE in E2

put AAA in G6, in H6 put the following formula =SUMIFS(C:C,E:E,"TRUE",B:B,G6)

if there is trash data in the blank cells like random spaces and whatnot use =isblank(trim(d2))

i loooove pivot tables but sometimes they just make file sizes too big if using a bunch of them in a single workbook, i also get tired of refreshing them.